# Fetch products from several SKUs where their price don't match from a list

Tags: magento2, products, search-criteria

I have a predefined list of SKUs with prices in an array, and I would like to return the products within Magento that matches those SKUs **but not** the price. As a quick solution, I have constructed an SQL query that does this (attribute 77 is the product price):

```sql
SELECT product.sku FROM catalog_product_entity product
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal price
ON product.entity_id = price.entity_id AND price.attribute_id = 77
WHERE (product.sku = 'FR050866' AND price.value != 132.2)
OR (product.sku = 'FR050869' AND price.value != 55.06)
OR (product.sku = 'FR230116' AND price.value != 210.93)
OR (product.sku = 'FS010048' AND price.value != 37.63)
OR (product.sku = 'FS010049' AND price.value != 13.44)
```

I then retrieved the matching SKUs as an array, and plugged it into the SearchCriteria:

```php
// Fetch the SKUs as an array
$product_skus_to_amend = $connection->fetchCol($sql);

// Find the products by those SKUs
$this->_filterGroup->setFilters([
    $this->_filterBuilder
     ->setField('sku')
     ->setConditionType('in')
     ->setValue($product_skus_to_amend)
     ->create()
]);

$this->_searchCriteria->setFilterGroups([$this->_filterGroup]);
$products = $this->_productRepositiry->getList($this->_searchCriteria);
```

Is there a better method of doing this that doesn't rely on creating my own SQL query, thus potentially only requiring one database call, instead of the two using the method above? I've been trying to figure this out using the `Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface` or `Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder` classes, but to no avail. Every guide I have found, which included [Magento's Documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/searching-with-repositories.html),  constructs queries like the below:

```sql
WHERE (x OR y) AND (a OR b)
```

However I can't find anything that constructs the below:

```sql
WHERE (x AND y) OR (a AND b)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use addAttributeToFilter for this and use `array('nlike' =>`

```
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku');  
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price'); 
   // Get all SKUS
                $allowedSku = array(
                                        array("finset" => array('FR050866')),
                                        array("finset" => array('FR050869')),
                                        array("finset" => array('FR230116')),
                                        array("finset" => array('FS010048')),
                                        array("finset" => array('FS010049')),
                                      );    

                $notallowedPrice = array(
                                            array("finset" => array('77')),
                                            array("finset" => array('132.2)),
                                            array("finset" => array('55.06')),
                                            array("finset" => array('210.93')),
                                            array("finset" => array('37.63')),
                                            array("finset" => array('13.44')),
                                          ); 
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
                            array('attribute'=>'sku', 'finset'=>$allowedSku),
                            array('attribute'=>'price', array('nlike' => notallowedPrice),

    ));
```

Useful link:
https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/addattributetofilter/